# Differential equation by power series with IVP not at $0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, boundary-value-problem

I was wondering whether one could solve a differential equation with initial value at $x_0\neq 0$. I think that the series must converge for $x=x_0$, otherwise the IVP wouldn't make sense. It seems as though one needs to know the value at which the series converges evaluated at $x_0$. However, it might be difficult to know this value when one can't express the series as a sum ($\sum$ notation) but rather as a sum of terms in the form $a_1+a_2x+\dotsc$.

So, could one solve an IVP not at $0$ if we have a strange summation? Is there any technique apart from finding the value at which the series converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several questions (it seems) involved here, some of which are unclear.

To answer your first question: yes, you can solve an IVP with conditions specified at $x_0\not=0$. You simply take the power series to be centered at $x_0$ and proceed as always to determine the coefficients $a_n$.
$$
y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n=a_0+a_1(x-x_0)+a_2(x-x_0)^2+\cdots\tag{1}
$$
Note that this ansatz does *not* result in terms of the form $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$ as you said. But this is a good thing since our initial condition(s) are specified at $x_0\not=0$.

Just like when $x_0=0$, your method will differ depending on whether $x_0$ is an ordinary point or singular point of the given equation.

As for a technique which determines the values of $x$ for which the series above converges, the answer again is "yes". You find the radius and interval of convergence of $(1)$ just like you did in calculus class (e.g., using the Ratio Test and checking the endpoints separately).

Comment: I thought about solving the power series centered at 0 and then evaluating the series at $x_0$. Sorry if I was too unclear.

Comment: Yes, I understood. I hope you can see why $(1)$ above is a better way to go: with an IC of the form $y(x_0)=y_0$ we quickly see that $a_0=y_0$ and similarly if we had $y'(x_0)=y_1$, we would see $a_1=y_1$.

Comment: Great!! Cheers.